# PKIX path building failed Salesforce

Tags: web-services, salesforce

I have a connection between Salesforce and SAP using a WS in an application in a server. The connection works until a SSL certificate was installed in the server. After the installation of the certificate I got this error when I made the request to the application:

```
System.HttpRequest retrying request in response to handshake failure: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

System.CalloutException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What could be the solution to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue? If yes please post your answer